# How can I deploy a web app with sbt 0.11?

Tags: scala, jetty, sbt, web-deployment, xsbt-web-plugin

it seems that both the jetty-run and jetty commands are missing from SBT 0.11. Either that or I am doing something very wrong. I am simply running sbt, then trying to run jetty-run. I have defined a web.xml file in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml which contains the following information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"> </web-app>
```

I am simply trying to deploy a blank web-app using the latest SBT. I cannot find any documentation or updated examples for doing so. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from sbt 0.8 (xsbt branch), if I remember correctly, web support goes as a **[standalone plugin](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin)**. Here you can find [instructions](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin/wiki) on how to install and use it. In general, this new plugin fully supports the regular workflow of a legacy SBT (e.g., `jetty-run`, `jetty-reload`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you, perfect! I hope others will find this instead of relying on outdated tutorials!